# Strange behaviour using ioredis or node_redis when testing hset and hget

Tags: node.js, redis, mocha.js, node-redis, ioredis

Hoping someone could shed some light on this.  I can't for the life of me find what the problem is.

**Problem:**

I am trying to add a value to Redis in one file using *hset* and get that value in a different file using *hget*.  What ends up happening in the test case is that the value is set but *hget* returns null as if nothing was there.

**Attempt:**

The really weird part happens when I try to get the value immediately after setting it in the **same** file.  It actually works as normal!  Check this out...

```
// FYI: This is co-mocha so the generator function is okay
describe('Route', () => {
  it('should return the value currently set in Redis', function* () {
    const link = 'this-is-a-link';
    yield redis.hset('i:metadata', 'stream', link); // using ioredis
    const response = yield request.send(); // requests to my Koa server
    expect(response.body.stream).to.equal(link); // expected null to equal 'this-is-a-link'
  });
});
```

and you can see the route is simply...

```
// FYI: This is a Koa route reference with a HTTP GET on '/'
exports.get = function* () {
  const stream = yield redis.hget('i:metadata', 'stream'); // using ioredis
  this.body = { stream }; // holds a value of null
};
```

If I insert that *hget* immediately below my *hset* in my test case the value is retrieved perfectly.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

**Note:**

Before anyone suggests, I have already listened for the connected event and that shouldn't matter because I can *hget* the value immediately below the *hset* and it works.  This problem also persists with a promisified *node_redis* install.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve it for different files?